# awk change one column with another

Tags: awk

I want to substitute column 2 os a db file like this

```
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('2', '33', '3', '1975', '3', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('4', '23544', '1', '1987', '3', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('2', '343', '3', '1975', '3', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('4', '21', '1', '1987', '3', '1', '1');
```

I have tried

`awk -F\' '{print NR-1,$2}'`

Is possible to subsitute column2 with NR-1?

I want a result like this(see the second numeric field)

```
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('2', '1', '3', '1975', '3', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('4', '2', '1', '1987', '3', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('2', '3', '3', '1975', '3', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('4', '4', '1', '1987', '3', '1', '1');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F\' -vOFS=\' '{$4=FNR}1' file
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('2', '1', '3', '1975', '3', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('4', '2', '1', '1987', '3', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('2', '3', '3', '1975', '3', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ('4', '4', '1', '1987', '3', '1', '1');
```

Comment: Doesn't work fine

Comment: @elbarna: What's the problem?

Comment: The correct line is awk -F\' -vOFS=\' '{$2=FNR}1' probably i explain my question bad,so i accept your asnwer as good solution thanks

Comment: @elbarna: As your describe output, it's `$4`, not `$2`.

Comment: Yes but starting reading from number is n°2